# How to show all the fields of a custom content type via the view module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I' using drupal 6.x and I ve created a custom content type called Task.
I can add content to the tasks, so far so good.
Now I want to have a table to list all the content of the custom content type Task.

I ve set up a new view but I was not able to get all the fields that are 
available for that content type to show in a list.

What i set up in the default view was 
i ve set to rowstyle node.
How can I find all the fields which refer to my custom content type.
I can get some of the cck fields set up for the custom content type, but not the titel e.g..
Thanks,
with best regards,
Bernhard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question, your custom content type is a node, so in your view you can show the node title filtering by your custom content type of nodes.

I prefer to use the module Display Suite: http://drupal.org/project/ds which has integration with views to display a custom build mode of nodes instead of showing individual fields.

Comment: I did not find my CustomContent type. Where is the field I can choose the custom content type. If I chose fields I get a list box  group and if I sort for node I can  find all the fields for a node content type, but if I preview there are all nodes and not my custom content type. Where to set?

Comment: I added a Node Display and then i chosed my custom content type and it works. But in the default view i did not set the custom content type, and it was not possible, but in the default view i cannnot set the custom content type.  And i thougt the default display it the Base class diesplay. I m confused.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to set the custom content type in the view.
The trick is to add a display called node content.
In then there is a field called  node types.
In the default display i did not find a way.

Bernhard